# Google drive API for file preview in iframe

Tags: iframe, google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

Google drive file preview in iframe needs user to login but how it can be accomplished by API.

How can we get preview of Google drive files in web without login into Google account. In current scenario only public files are visible through embed link, we need to show preview of file in iframe which are not public and without login.

[image]

We need to show private files by Google drive API in iframe. But it always ask for login.

Comment: first question, are the files you're trying to access yours?

Comment: Yes files are mine. I want to do it with API. Once i get file resource json, i get preview url but if i try to open it in iframe it redirect me to gmail login screen. I want to do it with access token or api key.

Comment: not sure what else you expect. the files are private, thus requires login

Answer (score 1):

[Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) returns a [file resouce](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) a file resource contains the following parameter.

> webViewLink    string  A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

Note: This wont work with all file types.

Comment: How to use webViewLink to open private files in iframe.

Comment: You can try and  put the weblink into an iframe and see if it will open with that.    If it doesn't work then the simple answer is you cant.